# Norwegian Special character not supporting in Codeigniter 2.0.2

Tags: codeigniter, special-characters

I am trying to save some special norwegian characters like æøå ÆØÅ but this not saved properly in database. Sometimes such characters get trimmed and sometimes shown like Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥ Ã

I had used htmlentities to support such characters in Codeigniter 1.7 and works well.

So the problem came with new version of Codeigniter.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you can, try updating to 2.1 and check if it's still buggy

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one of our native languages in India (that had accented charcters), and I resolved it by changing   charset values to utf8_unicode_ci in database (table and fields compilation) and files related with data capture and display of data.

Let me know that helps you.

Comment: Krishna, can you share the table and script files, if possible, so that I can debug?

Comment: It worked after updating the database folder of system folder with latest version of CI 2.1 Thank you for your help.